# Проверка палиндромов

Tags: php

Нужно проверить слова из пяти символов, которые являются [палиндромами](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC). То есть читаются одинаково как слева, так и справа.

Подскажите, от чего отталкиваться для выполнения задания, литературу или примеры кода.

Comment: >с шаблоном имени файла: все внутренние символы - не буквы русского алфавита и младше квартала с правами только на запись.

Это что такое? О_о  
Да, уточняющий вопрос: Unix?

Comment: нет, XP
про задание, сама мало что понимаю, так что изменила вопрос, оставив только про слова

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function isPalindrome($w){
    for($i = 0, $l = strlen($w)-1, $il = ceil($l/2); $i < $il; ++$i)
        if($w[$i] != $w[$l-$i])
            return false;
    return true;
}

$text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.';

preg_match_all('/\b(\w{5})\b/i', $text, $m);
for($i = 0, $il = sizeof($m[1]); $i < $il; ++$i)
    if(isPalindrome($m[1][$i]))
        echo $m[1][$i], '<br />'; // а можно и в массив записать, чтобы использовать в дальнейшем
```

Comment: У вас не совсем правильное Re. Последнее слово (laborum) не будет учитываться, т.к. за ним нет пробельного символа<br>
Верным будет:

    /\b(\w{5})\b/

Comment: Верно, спасибо).

Comment: тело функции можно упростить до `return $w === strrev($w);`

Comment: А для utf-8 и символов с кодами больше 7F работать не будет.

Answer (score 2):

Не надо ничего усложнять.

1) В проверяемом слове - 5 букв, Если длина отлична от 5 - возвращаем false;

2) Если первый символ слова равен пятому И второй равен четвертому - возвращаем true;

3) В остальных случаях возвращаем false.

При желании можно заняться приведением букв к единому регистру, но в условии задачи этого нет.

```
   function isPal($w)
    {
        if (strlen($w) <> 5) return 0;
        if (($w[0] == $w[4]) && ($w[1] == $w[3])) return 1; 
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Вот, человек условие прочитал и только потом ответил.

Answer (score 1):

```
class palindrome{
    // Показать Подробнее
    public function getMorePalindrome($str){
        $sentence = mb_strtolower($str);
        $sentence = str_replace(' ', '', $sentence);

        return 'Из строки "'.$str.'" ('.$sentence.'::'.$this->strrev_enc($sentence).') получился "'.$this->getPalindrome($str).'" <hr>';
    }


    // Получить полиндром
    public  function getPalindrome($str) {  
        $sentence = mb_strtolower($str);
        $sentence = str_replace(' ', '', $sentence);

        // если строка пуста
        if(!mb_strlen($sentence)){
            return '';
        }

        $revSentence = $this->strrev_enc($sentence);

        // Если строка идентична
        if($sentence == $revSentence){
            return $str;
        }

        $arrP = $this->searchAllP($sentence, $revSentence);

        for($i=0, $palindrome='', $l=0; $i<count($arrP); $i++){
            $strLength = iconv_strlen($arrP[$i], 'UTF-8');
            if($l<$strLength){
                $l = $strLength;
                $palindrome = $arrP[$i];
            }           
        }

        return $palindrome;
    }

    // Делает инвертирование строки
    public  function strrev_enc($str){
        $str = iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $str);
        $str = strrev($str);
        $str = iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $str);
        return $str;
    }

    // Поиск всех полиндромов
    protected function searchAllP($str, $rev){
        $arrP = array();
        $words = preg_split('//u', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);  

        for($i=0; $i<count($words); $i++){
            $reg = preg_quote($words[$i]);
            $arrP[] = $this->searchLengthP($reg, $rev, $i, $words);                             
        }

        return $arrP;       
    }

    // Поиск Конкретного полиндрома
    protected function searchLengthP(&$reg, &$rev, $i, &$words, $sw = ''){
        if(preg_match('#'.$reg.'#u', $rev, $m)){
            $sw = $m[0];

            if($i+1<count($words)){
                $i++;
                $reg .= preg_quote($words[$i]);

                return $this->searchLengthP($reg, $rev, $i, $words, $sw);
            }
        }

        return $sw;
    }
}

$palindrome = new palindrome();
echo $palindrome->getMorePalindrome("аlol Лепса Спел lol");
echo $palindrome->getMorePalindrome("Лепс+Спела");
echo $palindrome->getMorePalindrome("Моя Лепса Спела");
echo $palindrome->getMorePalindrome("Аргентина манит негра");
echo $palindrome->getMorePalindrome("Sum summus mus");
```

Из строки "аlol Лепса Спел lol" (аlolлепсаспелlol::lolлепсаспелlolа) получился "lolлепсаспелlol"

---

Из строки "Лепс+Спела" (лепс+спела::алепс+спел) получился "лепс+спел"

---

Из строки "Моя Лепса Спела" (моялепсаспела::алепсаспеляом) получился "лепсаспел"

---

Из строки "Аргентина манит негра" (аргентинаманитнегра::аргентинаманитнегра) получился "Аргентина манит негра"

---

Из строки "Sum summus mus" (sumsummusmus::sumsummusmus) получился "Sum summus mus"

---

Comment: Слишком переусложнено

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант (анг+рус)...

```
$l ='';
$a = 'херов орех';
$s = str_replace(' ', '', $a);
$s = mb_strtolower($s);    
$k = 2;
    if(preg_match("([a-z])", $s))$k = 1;
$c = str_split($s, $k);
$g = implode("", array_reverse($c));
    if ($s != $g) $l = ' не'; 
    echo "$a $l является палиндромом <br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем все так усложнять ?:)

```
<?
$string = "asdsa";
for ($i=strlen($string); $i >= 0; $i--)
    {
        $str .= $string[$i];
    }

if($str == $string)
    echo "True";
else
    echo "False";
```

?>

Читаем слово с конца. Далее, записываем в переменную $str каждый символ.
Если $str == $string - значит все тру :)))

Либо можно более навернуто :))) (Если нужно, например, вывести список слов из строки, которые будут подходить под условие)

```
$string = "asdsa1 jfsdd asdsa qwewq 12345 nghty mghtr trert";
$string = explode(" ", $string);
for($i=0; $i< count($string); $i++){
    for ($b=strlen($string[$i]); $b >= 0; $b--)
        {
            $str[$i] .= $string[$i][$b];
        }
    if($str[$i] == $string[$i])
        print_r($str[$i]."\r\n");
}
```

Посути - алгоритм несильно изменился.
Строку эксплодим по пробелам, получаем массив слов. И по старинке (как описано выше) :)

Comment: Для вашего варианта надо : <br>
2*Len + 2 операций для обеспечения работы цикла; 2*Len операций для чтения и сохранения символа; до 3*Len операций для посимвольного сравнения строк<br>
Для варианта @ling : <br>
2*Len/2 + 6 операций для обеспечения работы цикла; до 4*Len/2 операций для посимвольного сравнения строк<br>
Итого: Ваш - 4Len+2+3*Len*K; Не Ваш  - Len+6 + 2Len*K.<br>
Ваш вариант медленнее более чем в 2 раза)

Comment: тоже очень сложно ))
свой вариант написал)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str='abccba';
$strrev=strrev($str);
if ($str==$strrev) {echo 'это палиндром!!!!';}
else {echo 'это <b>нифига</b> не палиндром!!!';}
```

Comment: И тут скорость хромает) абсолютно равна @Станислава

Comment: да что вы ) что именно хромает? в каком месте?
у вас регулярка, вот что дает убыток скорости, а не простое сравнение и strrev

Comment: Вы-бы хоть ознакомились с тем что там написано. Регулярка - для вытаскивания всех слов. Я говорю только про функции сравнения палидром/не палидром.

Comment: а с чего вы вообще взяли, что надо парсить текст? в вопросе ничего об этом не сказано.

я как раз ознакомился
>Нужно проверить слова из пяти символов, которые являются палиндромами. То есть читаются одинаково как слева, так и справа.
Подскажите, от чего отталкиваться для выполнения задания, литературу или примеры кода.


где тут хоть слово про то, что надо выбирать слова из кучи текста?

>Я говорю только про функции сравнения палидром/не палидром.

так укажите, почему мой вариант слишком медленный, и покажите свой.

Comment: @ling сделал более универсальный код. Я не пойму, что вы пытаетесь сказать?<br>
Повторю свои слова:

    function isPalindrome($w){
        for($i = 0, $l = strlen($w)-1, $il = ceil($l/2); $i < $il; ++$i)
            if($w[$i] != $w[$l-$i])
                return false;
        return true;
    }

Быстрее ( по кол-ву операций, конкретно в PHP - может и не так, ибо что конкретно делает интерпритатор не ясно ), чем 

    function isPalindrome($w){
        $strrev=strrev($str);
        if ($str==$strrev) return true;
        else return false;
    }

Comment: о, а обоснования есть какие-то?
я чего то не пойму вашей логики.

Comment: Обоснование есть к ответу @Станислава, strrev - практически тоже самое что его цикл

P.S. О краткости и ясности - безусловно, ваше лучше)

Почему-же быстрее ( худший вариант - палиндром, строка == массив ):<br>
Развернуть массив: цикл по массиву, копирование на каждом шаге<br>
Сравнить массив: цикл по массиву, сравнение на каждом шаге<br>
Сравнить посимвольно начало с концом: цикл по половине массива, сравнение на каждом шаге<br>
Итого: <br>
развернуть и сравнить - 2 цикла по массиву и по операции на каждом шаге<br>
сравнить посимвольно - цикл по половине массива и по операции на каждом шаге

Comment: а можете линкануть, где можно почитать о вашем способе подсчитывать операции, чтобы я вас мог понять?.. ато ну никак не вкурю, почему у меня медленный способ. ИМХО лаконичнее разработчиков написать функцию strrev сложно, все таки это их работа. а strrev написана ими, и это есть самый простой способ проверить строку туда и обратно. А если еще учесть что strrev работает на с (т.е. ее основой является код в С) то работать она явно будет быстрее.

все ясно, думаю не стоит продолжать, если строка == массив, то я пойду че нить полезное поделаю.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю еще один вариант поиска палиндромов с формой на русском и английском языках:

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['w'])) { 
    $p = $_REQUEST['w'];
    $r="";
    $p = mb_strtolower($p);
    $p = str_replace(' ', '', $p);
    $c = mb_strlen($p, 'utf-8');
    for ($i=1; $i<=$c; $i++) {
        $r .= mb_substr($p, -$i, 1, 'utf-8');
    }
    if ($p == $r){
        echo "$p является палиндромом <br>";
    } else {
        echo "$p не является палиндромом <br>"; 
    }
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
  Ввести слово: <input type="text" name="w" value=""><br />
  <input type="submit" name="doSub" value="Найти">
</form>
```

Comment: Код можно улучшить, добавив отступы. Также в Вашем коде есть много вещей, не связанных с исходной задачей: `$_REQUEST`, использование кодировки `utf-8`, `echo`, html-код, форма и прочее... Видится, что всё это избыточно для данной задачи.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий и замечания, я еще только учусь и мне нужно было выполнить задание на поиск палиндрома с учетом русского языка, я не нашла нужного ответа на форуме, сделала задание сама, и вроде бы получилось :), поэтому решила поделиться своим решением и конечно же получить замечания от мэтров программирования.

Answer (score 0):

У меня была подобная задачка, только нельзя было пользоваться циклами.
Я начинающий, поэтому скорей всего код не оптимален, но вроде работает.

```
function isPalindrome($text) {
    static $i = 0;

    $length = strlen($text);
    $middle = ceil($length/2);
    $text_1 = str_split($text);

    if ($i < $middle) {
    if ($text_1[$i] == $text_1[$length-$i-1]) {
        ++$i;
        isPalindrome($text);
    }
}

if ($i == $middle) return true;
}
```